# MySQL + CodeIgniter + Click Tracking Unique & Total CLicks

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Trying to track outbound clicks on advertisements, but im having troubles constructing the query to compile all the statistics for the user to view and track.

I have two tables, one to hold all of the advertisements, the other to track clicks and basic details on the user. ip address, timestamp, user agent.

I need to pull all of map_advertisements information along with Unique Clicks based on IP Address, and Total Clicks based on `map_advertisements.id` to be showin in a table with rows. 1 row per advertisement and two of its columns will be totalClicks and totalUniqueClicks

Aside from running three seperate queries for each advertisement is there a better way to go about this?

**I am using MySQL5 PHP 5.3 and CodeIgniter 2.1**

```
#example of an advertisements id
$aid = 13;
SELECT
 *
 count(acl.aid)
 count(acl.DISTINCT(ip_address))
FROM
 map_advertisements a
 LEFT JOIN map_advertisements_click_log acl ON a.id = acl.aid
WHERE
 a.id = $aid;
```

#### map_advertisements

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `map_advertisements`
-- ----------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `map_advertisements`;
CREATE TABLE `map_advertisements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `youtube_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('video','picture') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'video',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

#### map_advertisements_click_log

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `map_advertisements_click_log`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `map_advertisements_click_log`;
CREATE TABLE `map_advertisements_click_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `browser` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem seems to be in your query there is no column with the name totalClicks in your table and distinct keyword is also used incorrectly. Try this:

```
SELECT     *, count(acl.id) as totalClicks, count(DISTINCT acl.ip_address) as uniqueClicks
FROM       map_advertisements a
LEFT JOIN  map_advertisements_click_log acl ON a.id = acl.aid
WHERE      a.id = $aid;
```

Comment: i have updated my qusetion, to reflect the proper psuedo sql. You have the column ordering right though. I will run this query in phpmyadmin and see what kind of results i get. if it works ill port it to CodeIgniter.

Comment: this query worked great, ill update my question with the CI code i used to run this query.